# QT Event filter not working with multiple buttons

Tags: c++, qt, events, keypress, eventfilter

I am trying to create a simple game in QT that uses event filter to catch keys pressed. It worked correctly until I implemented 'speed up' once space button is pressed. I have such a method in main window:

```
QSet<int> keysClicked; //declared in header

bool MainClass::eventFilter(QObject* target, QEvent* event)
{
    if(event->type()==QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        keysClicked.insert(static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event)->key());
        qDebug() << static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event)->key();
    }
    else if(event->type()==QEvent::KeyRelease)
        keysClicked.remove(static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event)->key());
    return QWidget::eventFilter(target, event);
}
```

and then a timer which sends `keysClicked` each n msecs to an object that we control.

`keysClicked` set should be able to contain all currently pressed keys.

And there is a problem, as it should contain spacebar, key_up, and either key_left or key_right:

1. It works correctly when I am holding `spacebar, key_up and key_right`
2. It doesn't work when I am holding `spacebar, key_up and key_left` (left key press is not found in eventFilter)
3. It works correctly when I am holding `key_up and key_left`

Could someone explain me what is the problem and how could I fix it? (point 2.)

Comment: 1.go to page https://stackoverflow.com/  with chrome

2.press space bar to scroll down the page

3.press up/down arrow to move up/down

4.press left arrow and up arrow and space wont work

5.press right arrow and up arrow and space works

is it a keyboard limitation?

Comment: Thank You! That's actually more general problem than I thought. And as I see, it's related with 'Phantom Keystrokes'. Anyway - I will look for a different solution to release a 'sprint' in my game. Feel free to post it as an answer.